# Print the values from files

Tags: shell-script, test

I have two files $TMP_RPT_FILE and $TMP_RPT_FILE1 . In $TMP_RPT_FILE - Meter readings come and $TMP_RPT_FILE1 - Meter Id come . I want if any data came in any of those files it should print . I tried in this way but its not working. can any one will help me regarding this ?

```
if [ -s "$TMP_RPT_FILE" || -s "$TMP_RPT_FILE1" ]
then

        if  [ -s "$TMP_RPT_FILE" ] 
        then
        print "Meters with READINGS ONLY for $RPT_DT" > $RPT_FILE
    cat $TMP_RPT_FILE | uniq >> $RPT_FILE
        fi

        if [ -s "$TMP_RPT_FILE1" ]
        then
        print "Meters with id for $RPT_DT" > $RPT_FILE
        cat $TMP_RPT_FILE1 | uniq >> $RPT_FILE
        fi
    cat $RPT_FILE | \
    $MAILCMD -s "$HOST: Meters with READINGS Only and No Profile Data for $RPT_DT" $MAILLIST
fi
```

Comment: can you give us sample from two input file, and sample of ouput ?

Comment: @Archemar In $TMP_RPT_FILE - 0000000121313                                                                                          XXXXX12378                                                                                               In   $TMP_RPT_FILE1-  pppp126587376                                                                                          1rty257

Comment: I want a OR condition between this two

Comment: any one understand what may be the problem

Comment: is the if [ -s "$TMP_RPT_FILE" || -s "$TMP_RPT_FILE1" ] this syntax is correct or not ?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use a shell operator `||` within `test` (`[ ... ]`) construct.

Use `-o`

```
if [ -s "$TMP_RPT_FILE" -o -s "$TMP_RPT_FILE1" ]
```

or split into 2 tests.

```
if [ -s "$TMP_RPT_FILE" ] || [ -s "$TMP_RPT_FILE1" ]
```

Comment: ok.its working fine